# Is SHA 2 suitable for key derivation?

Tags: aes, key-derivation, sha-2

Let's imagine that I've got a number modulo `n` given by DH protocol. I want to use it as a key for  AES encryption. So I have to cut this number to fit it in AES (128,192 or 256 bits). I can use hash functions to achieve that, but what hash function is suitable for key deriviation? Can I use SHA2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In principle raw SHA2 is suitable for deriving an AES key from a DH shared secret.

But the "proper" solution is to use a KDF. My preferred choice is HKDF, which can use SHA256 as the underlying hash function. It allows you to derive several named key and keys longer than 256 bits from a single secret.

Comment: Does this answer assume that the shared secret isn't already a key?  I mean, if the DH handshake just exchanges randomized 256-bit data, then is any sort of KDF still required before using that 256-bit data as an AES key?

Comment: @Nat The output of Diffie-Hellman is a random element of the (sub)group you're doing DH in. It is not uniformly random when treat it as a binary string.

Answer (score 15):

Yes.

Actually any cryptographic hash function should be fine and allow you to *reduce* the problem of breaking your AES encryption to either:

- breaking your DH protocol, this follows from the fact that secure hash functions are meant to be "one-way" function.
- brute-forcing the AES key, since the output of a good hash function is distributed uniformly at random.

But as CodesInChaos mentioned in his answer, the good practice is to use a Key Derivation Function (KDF) to derive a key from a given output.

There are two different kind of KDFs:

- those you use when you have a poor entropy and are afraid of Dictionary Attacks (typically if you store/work with humanly memorable passwords) like [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2);
- those that you use when you have a good entropy, which is the case if you rely on the DH protocol to establish a common key. In the latter case, the [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) is completely suited for this, and is actually thought for such need-case.

The advantage of using [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) is that you already have all the nifty feature you should otherwise implement:

- you have a salt, so you can easily generate multiple keys
- you have the notion of label, so you can generate different keys based on their label
- you have the size as a parameter, so you can easily plug in another encryption function in case AES get broken without changing the key generation algorithm.